# Splitting EDMX Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm looking to split my EDMX models into their own project to be referenced across the different projects without having to recreate the models across projects.

I have one project that contains the Entity Data Model.
I have another project that will contain common items across the projects.
This common project, I would like it to contain the Entity Models and remove them from the Entity Data Model project.

In the common project, I add an EF dbContext Generator.
I change the .tt inputFile to point to the edmx file in the other project and remove the .tt file from the Entity Data Model project.

This works but how do I go about handling any changes to the Entity Data Model and carrying them over to the common project since the .tt file no longer exists?

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Looks like you solved my problem, can you comment on my post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55288485/entity-framework-only-edmx-without-templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. All I need to do is right click on the .tt file in the common model and choose 'Run Custom Tool'