# Entity Framework - only edmx without templates

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

We would like to add only .EDMX files without corresponding .tt files for context and entities. There is multiple reasons for this, but long story short - we would like to be able to have .EDMX and be able to refresh it from DB when needed.

Currently if I delete .tt files every time I "Update from DB" it will regenerate .tt files and entitites which we don't need.

Comment: Have you tried keeping the .tt files but deleting their content?

Comment: Yes. And it would be "kind of" ok but code becomes somewhat "dirty" with extra empty files under each EDMX ModelA.context.tt, ModelA.Context.cs, ModelA.tt, ModelA.cs.

Comment: Just curious: Whats the goal, behind having an EDMX, but no T4 templates, and therefore no Context and Entities? If it's database visualisation, aren't there better tools out there? And why not simple create a new project for the visualization?

Comment: It's a long story, but basically T4s don't do what we need. We need multi-files generated for different purposes. So, we will have contexts and entities but going to handle generation in our own code (based off EDMX) without using T4s. We _can_ make T4s work I assume but with complexity of what we do it seems that going our own generator will be more maintainable

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but couldn't you make you own generator a *Custom Tool* (its a property of the edmx) for the edmx? [Take a look here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2008/09/01/Customize-Code-Generation-in-EF.aspx), not that I have done that.

Comment: @katit, do you add something when you update from db? You can use "Transform Related Text Templates On Save" with value "False". With this enabled, the .tt files are only generated when e.g. you add a new table. (with empty .cs files)

Comment: Are you using git or tfs version control?

Comment: @kapsiR I tried that and it restored files if I do "Update from DB" without adding anything.

Comment: @KristófTóth We use SVN

Comment: @katit Would it be ok, if you only have two empty .tt files and eventually a .diagram file?

Comment: @kapsiR It would be perfect not have any files. Just .tt would work somewhat but in my tests even if I leave empty .tt files - it would generate empty .cs files under them. 1 for each .tt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's enough to have only the `.edmx` with two empty `.tt` files you can do that:

1. Add the Entity Data Model (EF Designer from database)
2. Cancel initial execution of the tools
3. Empty `Custom Tool` value on each `.tt` file and on the `.edmx` file
4. Delete contents of the `.tt` files if you want
5. Delete `.diagram` file

After this steps, you can update your `.edmx` file and nothing happens.

[image: Custom Tool empty]
[image: Final solution]

Comment: Looks like this is the best answer so far. You can ALSO delete .context.tt and it will "comply" with it. So, just Model1.tt required

Comment: The interesting part is, if I disable "Transform Related Text Templates On Save" after this steps, then I can delete all `.tt` files... Can you reproduce this too?

Comment: @katit It seems that it is enough to just remove the `Custom Tool` from the `.edmx` file

Comment: Nope. If I remove Model1.tt - it will recreate both .tt files on "update". Yes, I have "Transform.." disabled

Comment: In VS 2022, I had to keep both .tt files

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand fully, but I simply delete the pair of t4/tt files that are included with the model and the previously generated class files. They don't come back for EF6.

[image]

Then I delete them and I update model from database:

[image]

and they don't come back:

[image: they don't come back]

This is from EF 6.2:
[image]

Are you sure you're not dealing with some source control issue?

Comment: We dont have Model1.Designer.cs and we don't have Model1.edmx.diagram. When we do "Update Model from Database" they come back. It's EF6.2

Comment: Using 6.2 also, the designer.cs file will get created but it's just got a comment: `T4 code generation is enabled for model 'C:\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\Data\Model1.edmx'...` Try adding a new model, repeat my steps to see...

Comment: Just did that and it's restoring tts. I don't think it's source control because I can modify tts and then delete them after saving and it would restore with fresh unmodified tts. Also, when I do model I chose not to save connection string in .config and do the same on "update"

Comment: @katit it's actually impossible for .tt files to be regenerated. There's no mechanism in Visual Studio to recreate .tt files that are associated directly with the model. Tried this with EF5,even changing the `Code Generation Strategy` from T4, just creates db context

Comment: Not sure what do you mean impossible. According to other posters and other answers - people are seeing same behaviour. If you delete .tt files and leave just .edmx - every time you "update" - VS/EF tool will recreate both .tt files.

Comment: @katit it's impossible. tt/t4 files are created as part of the add to project step. These files control auto-generation of code files. They are not themeselves auto-generated. Happy to go to chat to to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190642/discussion-between-katit-and-reckface).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

1. Delete `.tt` files under your `.edmx` file.
2. Project -> Add -> New Item -> `EF 6.x DbContext Generator`
3. It will generate new `.tt` files. In these `.tt` files you can specify `.edmx` file path.
   [image]
4. Run these `.tt` files to generate `Model1` classes.
5. Disable `.tt` files (Don't delete content as you will need it if you want to update your entities later. Usually they generate new files when you save them)
   [image]
6. Update your `.edmx` (add/remove tables).
7. This will not generate new `.tt` files under edmx
8. And it will not update your entity classes.
9. And if you want to update your entity classes, then run `.tt` files.

[image]

I tried this and "Update Model From Database" didn't generate new .tt files. So hopefully your problem will be solved.

Comment: It would be kind of workaround, however we have multiple .edmx files and having separate templates for each will be messy

Comment: We have this solution in our workspace. Usually we have all edmx in one project (lets say DataLayer) and all entities in another project (Entities). This makes a separation and allows flexibility. Also we have modified our `.tt` to generate some custom code (like interfaces for classes).

Comment: @katit but with this solution, the tt files will now generate any .cs files so your problem will be solved. In fact, I think it's pretty difficult for .tt files to be autogenerated.

Comment: The good thing is that you don't delete anything. You just keep them separate and update each component whenever you want.